# What is the best way to draw line under html element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have input in div and I wanna draw line center and underneath till the point where div ends.Like below.
I couldnt find anything to implement this.So I expect your help.

[image]

Here sample fiddle

```html
<html>
<body>

<div style="border:1px solid black;height:200px">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```css
.lineLabel {
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.line:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  z-index: 0;
}

.line > input {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div style="border:1px solid black;height:200px">
    <label class="lineLabel" for="fname">First name:</label>
    <div class="line">
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The `input` needs another `div` around it so that its size can be used to find the centre. A pseudo-element is then used to draw the line.

Comment: Just a little refactor advice, using a CSS id (#) instead of a class could be bad practice assuming this line will be used on other input elements aswell. Creating double ID's.

Comment: Fully agree with that. I've updated this answer to use classes instead.